# Wordpress rewrite url

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I've been looking at rewriting rules for wordpress, since i have a site http://mysite.com/abc/def/ghi
, and I want to be able to visit http://mysite.com/def/ghi without having 'abc' in the URL.

All the tutorials I've been able to found only describe the opposite way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, `abc`, `/def` and `/ghi` folders are not in WP space?

Comment: yeah they are. i have a page as root called abc, but i do not want it in my urls

Comment: 'm still unclear as to how your WordPress is setup. If it's installed at the root, then why do you access it at /abc/def/ghi? If it's installed at the root like you say, then you should access it at http://mysite.com/, unless you are already doing some sort of rewriting.